# Get the content of terms and conditions by url?

Tags: magento-1.8, geturl

I know this is how you get the content of Terms and Condition,

```
<?php if (!$this->getAgreements()) return; ?>
<form action="" id="checkout-agreements" onsubmit="return false;">
<ol>
<?php foreach ($this->getAgreements() as $_a): ?>
    <li>
        <div id="agreement-block-<?php echo $_a->getId();?>" class="agreement-content <?php if (Mage::helper('opc')->getTermsType()):?>hidden<?php endif?>"<?php echo ($_a->getContentHeight() ? ' style="height:' . $_a->getContentHeight() . '"' : '')?>>
            <?php if ($_a->getIsHtml()):?>
                <?php echo $_a->getContent() ?>
            <?php else:?>
                <?php echo nl2br($this->htmlEscape($_a->getContent())) ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group checkbox">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" id="agreement-<?php echo $_a->getId()?>" name="agreement[<?php echo $_a->getId()?>]" value="1" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_a->getCheckboxText()) ?>" />
                <a class="button-cart-simple button-agreement" data-id="<?php echo $_a->getId();?>" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><?php echo $_a->getIsHtml() ? $_a->getCheckboxText() : $this->htmlEscape($_a->getCheckboxText()) ?></a>
            </label>
        </div>
    </li>
<?php endforeach ?>
</ol>
</form>
```

But can I access this page by using URL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no page to display the agreements. They appear in the checkout.
But you can create one.
Create a static page with this content.

```
{{block type="core/template" template="agreements/list.phtml"}}
```

Then create the template file `agreements/list.phtml` in your theme with this content:

```
<?php $agreements = Mage::getModel('checkout/agreement')->getCollection()
                    ->addStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
                    ->addFieldToFilter('is_active', 1); ?>

<?php if ($agreements->count()) : ?>
<form action="" id="checkout-agreements" onsubmit="return false;">
<ol>
<?php foreach ($agreements as $_a): ?>
    <li>
        <div id="agreement-block-<?php echo $_a->getId();?>" class="agreement-content <?php if (Mage::helper('opc')->getTermsType()):?>hidden<?php endif?>"<?php echo ($_a->getContentHeight() ? ' style="height:' . $_a->getContentHeight() . '"' : '')?>>
            <?php if ($_a->getIsHtml()):?>
                <?php echo $_a->getContent() ?>
            <?php else:?>
                <?php echo nl2br($this->htmlEscape($_a->getContent())) ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group checkbox">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" id="agreement-<?php echo $_a->getId()?>" name="agreement[<?php echo $_a->getId()?>]" value="1" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_a->getCheckboxText()) ?>" />
                <a class="button-cart-simple button-agreement" data-id="<?php echo $_a->getId();?>" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><?php echo $_a->getIsHtml() ? $_a->getCheckboxText() : $this->htmlEscape($_a->getCheckboxText()) ?></a>
            </label>
        </div>
    </li>
<?php endforeach ?>
</ol>
</form>
<?php endif;?>
```

You can adjust the markup if needed.
Then just view the page like any other cms page.

Comment: thanks. but why is it a list.phtml - `agreements/list.phtml`?

Comment: and where is `agreements/list.phtml`??

Comment: @tealau Because I say so...:). Just kidding. You can name the template how ever you want. It doesn't exist. You have to create it. Name it how ever you want but make sure you use the same template name in the  {{block}} directive

Comment: I just tested the code but it does not work though - `$agreements->count` returns `null`.

Comment: @tealau. Oups. My bad. I should be `count()` not  `count`. I fixed it.