# Terms and conditions as a static page url

Tags: onepage-checkout, cms, ce-1.9.0.1

I want to add a link to our terms and conditions in our newsletter, but I believe I need to create a cms page first, referencing the T's & C's from the onepage checkout.

I have come across this suggestion, [Get the content of terms and conditions by url?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/25658/get-the-content-of-terms-and-conditions-by-url/25660#) , which might be the answer I'm looking for, but I cannot figure out where to place the folder "agreements" within my theme.

I have followed the suggestion to the best of my ability, but no matter what I do, I only get a blank page.

Can anyone help in simple terms for a newbe?

Comment: Could you post the code/paths you added from the linked post? It may very well be an incorrect path issue, or something similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the agreements are loaded from the database in the block `Mage_Checkout_Block_Agreements` during checkout I would suggest that you could use the block type `checkout/agreements` in your cms page and then simply set your own template that loops through these agreements.

```
{{block type="checkout/agreements" template="agreements/list.phtml"}}
```

Then in your template file you can call the function `getAgreements`, this function either uses the agreements set against the block or loads them from the database.

```
<?php if ($this->getAgreements()): ?>
    <?php foreach ($this->getAgreements() as $_a): ?>
        <?php if ($_a->getIsHtml()):?>
            <?php echo $_a->getContent() ?>
        <?php else:?>
            <?php echo nl2br($this->escapeHtml($_a->getContent())) ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endforeach ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Aha! Thank you both for replying. I cannot say why, but the original post I referenced to (along with the suggestion from Kalpesh) didn't work. The moment I added the block into the CMS page, it cleared all content & showed a blank page. Your suggestion did the job perfectly, thanks David! PS: This was mostly so my newsletter subscribers can see our T's&C's. Now, would you by any chance know what keyword to use in order to show the subscriber's first name in the newsletter? {{var subscriber.CustomerFirstname}}, {{var get.CustomerName}}, {{fisrtname}} etc aren't working.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create your folder and file at `app/design/frontend/[package]/[theme]/template/` location. So it should be `app/design/frontend/[package]/[theme]/template/agreements/list.phtml` and here you have to put your t&c.

Make sure you create a CMS page with content `{{block type="core/template" template="agreements/list.phtml"}}` in admin as directed in the link you posted. Also, don't forget to clear the cache once everything is done.

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to get this to work without also putting the following code into the design tab of the custom page:

`<reference name="content"><block type="checkout/agreements" name="terms_content"  template="agreements/list.phtml" /></reference>`

As a nube, maybe I should have known that this had to be done when reading the answers above, but I didn't.